# how to search result by just changing parameter from url and hitting enter key in php

Tags: php, mysql

I want to Search Result by changing parameter value and hitting enter key in address.
When i Search on main page i use to pass the search keyword in url in this form

```
eg:->http://localhost/mydeals/searchListing.php?sRes=g
```

And now when I am on searchListing.php i want to just chan change the parameter of sRes to p like that and after that when i press enter key in adress bar i get the value in $_GET so how can i search it.

```
eg:->http://localhost/mydeals/searchListing.php?sRes=p
```

my php code which i had written in config file is.

```
if(isset($_POST['search2']))
    {
        if(trim($_POST['location2'])!="" && $_GET['sRes'] =="")
        {
            $_SESSION['dirLocation2'] = trim($_POST['location2']);
            header("location:".THIS_DOMAIN."searchListing.php?sRes=".$_SESSION['dirLocation2']);
        }else if($_GET['sRes'] !=""){
            $_SESSION['dirLocation2'] = trim($_GET['sRes']);
            header("location:".THIS_DOMAIN."searchListing.php?sRes=".$_SESSION['dirLocation2']);
        }else{
            header("location:".THIS_DOMAIN."index.php");    
         }
    }

    if (empty($_GET["sRes"])) {
        header("location:".THIS_DOMAIN."index.php");    
    } else{
        $_SESSION['dirLocation2'] = trim($_GET['sRes']);
            header("location:".THIS_DOMAIN."searchListing.php?sRes=".$_SESSION['dirLocation2']);
    }
```

Comment: Your question and code is not related. What is your actual problem? What are you trying to do?

Comment: i am trying to search reasult by just changing the parameter which i passed in url

Comment: $_POST['search2'] is the the name of buttun which i used to search for on main page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(isset($_POST['search2']))
    {
        if(trim($_POST['location2'])!="")
        {
            $_SESSION['dirLocation2'] = trim($_POST['location2']);
        header("location:".THIS_DOMAIN."searchListing.php?sRes=".$_SESSION['dirLocation2']);
        }
        else{
            header("location:".THIS_DOMAIN."index.php");    
         }
    }

if (empty($_GET["sRes"])) {

} else{
        $_SESSION['dirLocation2'] = trim($_GET['sRes']);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by checking url parameter like;

```
<?php

if (empty($_GET["sRes"])) {
    header("Location: index.php");
} else {
    $sResValue = $_GET["sRes"]; // p, or s
    // Do your search here
}
```

Comment: The page isn't redirecting properly
Fireox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete.

Comment: There is redirecting loop. Could you please post exact code in your question? I need to see your entire code to comment

Comment: There is no way to go redirection loop, How did you test it?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52722/discussion-between-ricky-and-huseyin-babal)